# Is their any way of adding google play billing into a Python project?

Tags: android, python-3.x, payment, upi

I am a Python developer who works to develop windows softwares generally. But my company wants an Android app to be developed by me using Python now.

I have gone through each and every way and I now probably know that how to convert a .Py file to .Apk file.

My question is that~
**How to add a feature of In App payments through paytm, UPI etc. In my app using Python.**

And unluckily, I have no idea how to do that. Please don't talk about django and flask websites and payment gateways they support in Python.

This is not a website but an app for Android.

Can you please tell me how can I add In App purchases in Python?

For extra info, I am using pygame and pgs4a to convert my Python to apk.

Searched everywhere on the internet and got only one clue,

InAppPy module which supports google play and app store billing in Python. But this will work only on Python 3.6+ whereas, pgs4a works only with Python 2.7. So I can not even use that.

Please help,
Thanks In advance.

Comment: Have you looked into Kivy? They have continued to develop a toolchain to build Python applications for Android… I would imagine they have hooked into the Google Play API.